# Speaker not shown symbl ai realtime transcript

Tags: webrtc

I have connected to symbl's streaming api through websocket and have sent the `start request` which looks like this;

```
{
        type: "start_request",
        meetingTitle: "Symbl Connect SIP",
        config: {
          confidenceThreshold: 0.5,
          languageCode: "en-US",
          speechRecognition: {
            encoding: "LINEAR16",
            sampleRateHertz:
              userType === "user" ? this.sampleRateUser : this.sampleRateAgent,
          },
          trackers: {
            enableAllTrackers: true,
            interimResults: true,
          },
 speaker: {
          ...speaker,
          name: userType,
        },
        },
       
      }
```

However when I bind to the `onmessage` event the realtime `transcription` and `message_response` doesn't have the `from`(`message_response`) or `user`(transcription) field which should have the name and userId. The output looks like this;

- `message_response`

```
messages: [
    {
      payload: {
        content: string,
        contentType: "text/plain",
      },
      id: string,
      channel: {
        id: "realtime-api",
      },
      metadata: {
        disablePunctuation: true,
        originalContent: string,
        words: string,
        originalMessageId: string,
      },
      dismissed: false,
      duration: {
        startTime: string,
        endTime: string,
        timeOffset: number,
        duration: number,
      },
      entities: [],
    },
  ]
```

- realtime transcription

```
{
    type: "recognition_result",
    isFinal: false,
    payload: {
      raw: {
        alternatives: [
          {
            words: [],
            transcript: "Hello",
            confidence: 0,
          },
        ],
      },
    },
    punctuated: {
      transcript: "Hello",
    }
}
```

The `user` and `from` fields are missing in this case.

I was expecting the output to be something like this;

```
{
    type: "recognition_result",
    isFinal: false,
    payload: {
      raw: {
        alternatives: [
          {
            words: [],
            transcript: "Hello",
            confidence: 0,
          },
        ],
      },
    },
    punctuated: {
      transcript: "Hello",
    },
    user: {
      name: "agent",
      userId: "agent@123.com",
    "id": "1a726dac-1c95-484d-a99e-69e36950bf32"
  }
```

or

```
{
      from: {
        id: string,
        name: string,
        userId: string,
      },
      payload: {
        content: string,
        contentType: "text/plain",
      },
      id: string,
      channel: {
        id: "realtime-api",
      },
      metadata: {
        disablePunctuation: true,
        originalContent: string,
        words: string,
        originalMessageId: string,
      },
      dismissed: false,
      duration: {
        startTime: string,
        endTime: string,
        timeOffset: number,
        duration: number,
      },
      entities: [],
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

To fix this issue all you have to do is to move the `speaker` object outside of the config object to the same level as the config. Like this;

```
{
        type: "start_request",
        meetingTitle: "Symbl Connect SIP",
        config: {
          confidenceThreshold: 0.5,
          languageCode: "en-US",
          speechRecognition: {
            encoding: "LINEAR16",
            sampleRateHertz:
              userType === "user" ? this.sampleRateUser : this.sampleRateAgent,
          },
          trackers: {
            enableAllTrackers: true,
            interimResults: true,
          },
        },
       speaker: {
          ...speaker,
          name: userType,
        },
      }
}
```